# How to setAdapter for carousel in motionlayout

Tags: android, carousel, android-adapter, android-motionlayout

I am developing an app for that i used carousel with motion layout for image slider but i couldn't populate the carousel.
And I am unable to set the adapter for the carousel how to populate the it with images or data.

Once this basic motion scene is created, we only need to add a Carousel helper to the layout and references those views (in the same order we implemented our previous/next animation).

**This is the XML file.**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_product_view_3d_scene">

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nature2"/>

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nature1"/>

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/nature"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Carousel
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:carousel_forwardTransition="@+id/forward"
        app:carousel_backwardTransition="@+id/backward"
        app:carousel_previousState="@+id/previous"
        app:carousel_nextState="@+id/next"
        app:carousel_infinite="true"
        app:carousel_firstView="@+id/imageView2"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView0,imageView1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**This is the motion scenefile.**

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/next"
        motion:duration="1000"
        android:id="@+id/forward">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/previous"
        android:id="@+id/backward">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

**This is the .java file.**

```java
    
public class ProductView_3d extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        Carousel carousel;
        int [] images = {R.drawable.nature1, R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.nature2};
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_view_3d);
    
            carousel = findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    
            carousel.setAdapter(new Carousel.Adapter() {
                @Override
                public int count() {
                    return images.length;
                }
    
                **@Override
                public void populate(View view, int index){
                }**
    
                @Override
                public void onNewItem(int index) {
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I implemented from the official documentation of android [link here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/carousel)

**But I am unable to populate the carousel could anyone help.
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding

```
((ImageView)view).setImageResource(images[index]);
```

to

```
 public void populate(View view, int index){
 }
```